# Fluid flow through a tank with multiple holes and a viscous solution

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

I'm working on a project and I need to figure out the flow rate of a system where the liquid is draining through multiple holes. The liquid is slightly viscous (1% sodium alginate solution, don't know viscosity for sure yet but might be 12-40 cps) and the diameter of each hole is about 2mm, with as many as 40 holes at the bottom of the tank. The tank itself should be between 40-50 cm wide but this isn't set in stone. I need some help with how to do these calculations because I need to optimize the flow rate of the system in regards to how high to make the tank, and how many holes to drill. This is because the system will also need to constantly replenish the amount of liquid in the tank to keep a constant pressure.

Unfortunately, I don't have any background on fluids and such, but I can try to provide as much information as possible. Sorry if this is too open-ended.